# clearTimeout does not work the way expected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement debounce function in vanilla JavaScript. I am not sure why clearTimeout does not clear the timeout object. In each event trigger, callback function setTimeout and if it is not more than 5 seconds from the last call, it clears the timeout that just created. But I don't see the timeout being cleared.

HTML:

```
<html>

  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='move'>

    </div>
    <div id='result'>

    </div>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
 var area;
 var result;

 function init() {
   area = document.querySelector('#move');
   area.addEventListener('mousemove', debouce1);
   result = document.querySelector('#result');
 }

 function updateResult(event) {
   let xCordinate = event.clientX;
   let yCordinate = event.clientY;
   result.textContent = `${xCordinate} , ${yCordinate}`;
 }



 function debounce1(fn, time) {
   let firstTime = true;
   let start;
   return function() {
       if (firstTime) {
         fn.apply(null, arguments);
         firstTime = false;
         start = new Date();
       } else {
         let now = new Date();
         let timer = setTimeout(() => {
           fn.apply(null, arguments);
           start = new Date();
         }, time)
         if (now - start < 4000) {
           console.log('too fast');
           clearTimeout(timer);
           console.log(now - start);
           console.log(timer);
           start = new Date();
         }

       }
   }
   init();
```

Comment: `I don't see the timeout being cleared` how do you expect to **see** this? does the console show `too fast`? and then a number? `clearTimeout(timer)` should "clear" that timeout, it doesn't change the value of `timer`

Comment: Also `debounce1` is passed to `addEventListener` directly instead of calling it and passing the result.

Comment: Are you expecting the variable `timer` to be something different after calling `clearTimeout(timer)`?

Comment: `start` and `now` are `instanceof Date`. You would need to `.getTime()` on those, realizing that would give you milliseconds.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Am I not clearing the timeout were I call clearTimeout(timer)? I thought It would clear the timer

Comment: yes, so are you saying that the timer still "goes off"?

Comment: @StackSlave -try `console.log(new Date - 1)` - javascript coerces the values of the object to Number when performing subtraction

Answer (score -1):

There are quite a few issues with the code posted.

```
area.addEventListener('mousemove', debouce1);
```

It's `debounce1` not `debouce1`

And it should be something like

```
area.addEventListener('mousemove', debounce1(updateResult, 1000));
```

Calling `fn.apply` with `null` means the code loses the fact that event handlers are called with `this` set to the element that the listener was bound to

The code is calling `init` inside `debounce1`

Another minor comment, you can call `Date.now()` or `performance.now()` to get number that represents time as a number which is arguably more appropriate than creating `Date` objects.

Also not sure what the point of even having a `clearTimeout` call is.

Here's a another implementation of `debounce1`. It passes on the last set of arguments and the last `this`. Made `updateResult` show `this.id` so we can check that `this` is correct for the callback.

```js
'use strict';

const result = document.querySelector('#result');

function init() {
  const area = document.querySelector('#move');
  area.addEventListener('mousemove', debounce1(updateResult, 1000));
}

function updateResult(event) {
  const xCordinate = event.clientX;
  const yCordinate = event.clientY;
  result.textContent = `${this.id}: ${xCordinate} , ${yCordinate}`;
}

function debounce1(fn, time) {
  let lastArgs;
  let lastThis;
  let timeoutQueued;
  let debounceTime = 0;

  return function(...args) {
    lastThis = this;
    lastArgs = [...args];
    if (!timeoutQueued) {
      timeoutQueued = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        timeoutQueued = false;
        fn.apply(lastThis, lastArgs);
      }, debounceTime);
      debounceTime = time;
    }
  };
};

init();
```

```css
#move {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='move'></div>
<div id='result'>
```